# New Line character in Pulumi as a secret/value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pulumi

I would like to store a key as a secret in Pulumi in the configuration.

The key has the following structure

`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx -----END PRIVATE KEY-----`

But, when adding it into the configuration, I face 2 problems:

- A config setting starting by `-----` gives error.
- Pulumi is converting `\n` to `\\` so it gives error while trying to pull the key as a secret.

I've tried all the formats, to store it as a `--plaintext` and other solutions proposed [here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/cli/pulumi_config_set/) but didn't work.

I would appreciate if someone can bring some light here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pipe the key from `stdin` like so:

```sh
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa | pulumi config set secretKey --secret
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. It preserved the `\n` as well.